# ESP32: BLE transmission speed is very slow

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32, arduino-ide, arduino-esp32

I am trying to build an Android app that interfaces with the ESP32 using BLE. I am using the RxBluetoothKotlin library from Vincent Masselis for the Android side. For the ESP32 side, I am using the default Kolban libraries that are included in the Arduino IDE. My phone is a OnePlus 5T and my ESP32 is a MH ET Live ESP32DevKIT. My Android app can be found [here](https://github.com/Amanoo/RxBluetoothKotlin/tree/master/demo-app), and my ESP32 program [here](https://github.com/Amanoo/RxBluetoothKotlin/tree/master/demo-app-esp32-companion).

The whole system works pretty much perfectly for me in terms of pure functionality. That is to say, every button does what it's supposed to do, and I get the exact behaviour I had expected to get. However, the communication itself is very slow. Around 200 bytes/second. My test button in the Android app requests a bunch of text data from the ESP32, and displays this in a dialog. It also lists a number which represents the time between request and reception in milliseconds. Using this, I get around 2 seconds for 440 bytes of data. When I send less data, the time decreases approximately linearly with data size. 40 bytes of data will take around 200ms, and 20 bytes or under typically takes less than 100ms.

This seems rather slow to me. From what I understand, I should be able to at least get a few kilobytes per second. I have tried to check the speed using nRF Connect, but I get the same 2 seconds timespan for my data transfer. This suggests that the problem is not in my app, since I also have it with a completely different app. I also put the code in my main loop inside of callbacks instead (which I probably should have done in the first place), but this didn't change things at all. I have tried taking the microcontroller and my phone to a few different locations, hoping to eliminate interference. I have tried to mess with BLEDevice::setPower and BLEDevice::setMTU, as well as setting RxBluetoothGatt.requestMtu(500) on the Android side. Everything so far seems to have had little to no effect. The only thing that did anything, was adding the line "pServer->updatePeerMTU(0,500);" in my loop during the connection phase. This caused the first 23 bytes of data to be repeated whenever I pressed the test button in my app, and made the data transfer take about 3 seconds. If I'm lucky, I can get maybe a bit under 1.8 seconds for 440 bytes, but this is a very small change when I'm expecting an order of magnitude of difference, and might even be down to pure chance rather than anything I did.

Does anyone have an idea of how to increase my transfer speed?

Comment: Using `requestMtu` does not set the MTU,  but request the MTU to be negotiated between the two devices. You requested an MTU of 500, your BLE device might not be able to set the MTU that high. You can listen to the [onMtuChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback#onMtuChanged(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt,%20int,%20int)) event to see the actually used MTU

Comment: I seem to be sending and receiving 440 byte packets just fine, actually. It is just very slow. I was just messing with the MTU size on both ends, but it doesn't seem to me that it's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The data transmission speed is mainly influenced by the Bluetooth LE connection interval (between 7.5 ms and 4 seconds) and is negotiated between the master (central unit) and the peripheral device. The master establishes a connection with a parameter set and the peripheral can propose to change this parameter set. In the end, however, the central unit decides which parameter set is to be used.

But the Bluetooth connection interval cannot be changed by an Android applications directly, which normally act as the central role. Instead it can [request a connection priority](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt#requestConnectionPriority(int)) which is known to have an influence on the connection interval.

Comment: I looked for the "Request Priority" option in the nRF Connect app, and pressed "high". The logs show I got a 15ms interval after this. However, it still takes at least 1.6 seconds to get any feedback. By using normal priority, it becomes about 3 seconds, and with Low power priority about 6. Doesn't seem like the connection priority was the issue. By default, the nRF app starts at a 7.5ms interval, then switches over to 47.5. 15 seems to make it slightly faster, but I'm still off by entire orders of magnitude.

Comment: I have messed around with partition schemes in my IDE, uploaded the code to my ESP32, then messed around some more with a larger MTU and higher priority, and now it seems I'm getting about 10kByte/s. Still not as fast as BLE should be capable of, but a lot closer. The weird thing is, MTU and priority didn't seem to do much earlier. I'm really not sure why it's woirking now.

Comment: @Amanoo do you really have 10kByte/s or do you mean 10 kbit/s? Background: 10 kbit/s is near to the theoretical max. throughput of 10.6 kbit/s for writing data @ an event length of 7.5 ms. 
The guys over there at Punch Through wrote an comprehensive article about  "Bluetooth PHY – How it Works and How to Leverage it" https://punchthrough.com/crash-course-in-2m-bluetooth-low-energy-phy/

Comment: I'm sending about 440 characters in 40-45ms from the ESP32 to the phone (read command). So just over 10 characters per millisecond, or just over 10000 per second. One char being one byte, of course. According to the Espressif docs, the maximum throughput of Bluetooth LE communication between ESP32 boards can reach up to 700 Kbps, which is about 90 KB/s. I should actually be able to reach faster speeds, according to Espressif. But my current speed should be fine already.

Comment: But the same Chapter of the FAQ states:
"The throughput of ESP32 Bluetooth LE depends on various factors such as environmental interference, connection interval, MTU size, and the performance of peer devices." https://docs.espressif.com/projects/espressif-esp-faq/en/latest/software-framework/ble-bt.html#what-is-the-throughput-of-esp32-bluetooth-le
And also the Link I mentioned earlier states:
"Unfortunately, these benefits make the 2.4GHz band a popular choice, and as a result, overcrowding and congestion are common issues."

Comment: The values given by Espressif can only be achieved in the laboratory and if any interference can be excluded.

Comment: Yeah, it's a theoretical maximum. At any rate. I'm happy with my achievements so far. I'm in the same order of magnitude as the theoretical maximum, and I'm content with that. I've achieved a reasonable enough speed.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem as you and was happy to find your comment:

> I have messed around with partition schemes in my IDE, uploaded the code to my ESP32, then messed around some more with a larger MTU and higher priority, and now it seems I'm getting about 10kByte/s.

So after messing around with all this settings I found working solution for me (**16 kB/s**).

Here is my summary, sorted by priority:

1. Be sure to request MTU from the client side (i.e. Android app: put `gatt.requestMtu()` after discovering services) and **not** from the server side (ESP: `BLEDevice::setMTU();`)
2. Request high connection priority from the Android side: `gatt.requestConnectionPriority(BluetoothGatt.CONNECTION_PRIORITY_HIGH)`
3. Play with the payload size. As [this figure](https://punchthrough.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/graph-2-703w.png) shows, adding even one byte to the payload may significantly decrease the speed (figure taken from [this article](https://punchthrough.com/maximizing-ble-throughput-part-2-use-larger-att-mtu-2/)). As table below shows, the speed decreased 3x in my case (last table).
4. Remove unnecessary flags from your characteristic so you can increase payload. Just `BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ` is enough for me.
5. Setting different power by `esp_ble_tx_power_set(ESP_BLE_PWR_TYPE_DEFAULT,ESP_PWR_LVL_P9);` had no effect for me

**Results - changing priority:**

```
| Speed [B/s] |  Priority  | MTU | Payload |
|-------------|------------|-----|---------|
|     190     |    DCK     | 500 |   495   |
|    1035     |  LOW_POWER | 500 |   495   |
|    5522     |  BALANCED  | 500 |   495   |
|   16566     |    HIGH    | 500 |   495   |
```

**Results - changing MTU:**

```
| Speed [B/s] |  Priority  | MTU | Payload |
|-------------|------------|-----|---------|
|     571     |    HIGH    |  23 |   495   |
|    1183     |    HIGH    |  46 |   495   |
|    4141     |    HIGH    | 230 |   495   |
|    5522     |    HIGH    | 460 |   495   |
|   16566     |    HIGH    | 500 |   495   |
```

**Results - changing payload size:**

```
| Speed [B/s] |  Priority  | MTU | Payload |
|-------------|------------|-----|---------|
|     100     |    HIGH    | 500 |      1  |
|     400     |    HIGH    | 500 |     10  |
|    3400     |    HIGH    | 500 |    100  |
|   16566     |    HIGH    | 500 |    495  |
|    5533     |    HIGH    | 500 |    496  | (!)
```

When I had all flags `BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ | BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_NOTIFY | BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_INDICATE` I was able to send "only" 455 bytes at 15233 B/s.

I know this response is a bit late, but somebody may still find it helpful:)

Comment: Assuming LE Data Length Extension with length = 251 bytes, that would explain why 495 is much better than 496. The first L2CAP chunk of your GATT packet contains a 4 byte header plus a 3 byte ATT header, leaving 244 bytes left for payload. The second chunk can use all 251 bytes for payload, and 244+251=495. With an extra byte, you need an additional Link Layer packet.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I've never managed to study BLE in depth and often use trial and error tactics. With this background it makes much more sense though.

Comment: You could also try to measure performance with 244 bytes notifications. Should be pretty good.

Comment: I tried, at 244 I get 8200 B/s which is fine. However, by trying different payload sizes (200,244,245,250,300,...) I get that speed more or less linearly increases with the payload size up to 496 where it drops.